# String.format gives `,` instead of `.`

Tags: android-studio, string-formatting

`String.format("%.2f",0.333333);`
gives `0,33` but I'd like to have `0.33`.

Comment: @Martin Yes. How can I fix it to `.` with a command ?

Answer (score 1):

Put Locale.ROOT inside, like this:

```
String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.2f",0.333333);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.format()` picks the locale you are in. You have to specify the locale explicitly if you want. instead of,

You can use it like this:

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", 0.333333)
```